# Skipping the Angular Material install prompts (Using Defaults)?

Tags: angular, angular-material

This used to work for bypassing the prompts during an Angular Material install:

```
ng add @angular/material --interactive=false
```

However it no longer works.  How do we skip the prompts?

Here's a sample command attempt using `interactive=false`:

```
Would you like to proceed? (Y/n) 
oleersoy@Oles-MacBook-Pro ng % ng add @angular/material --interactive=false
Node.js version v19.8.1 detected.
Odd numbered Node.js versions will not enter LTS status and should not be used for production. For more information, please see https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/.
ℹ Using package manager: npm
✔ Found compatible package version: @angular/material@15.2.7.
✔ Package information loaded.

The package @angular/material@15.2.7 will be installed and executed.
Would you like to proceed? (Y/n)
```

And here's a sample attempts with `--defaults`:

```
oleersoy@Oles-MacBook-Pro ng % ng add @angular/material --defaults         
Node.js version v19.8.1 detected.
Odd numbered Node.js versions will not enter LTS status and should not be used for production. For more information, please see https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/.
ℹ Using package manager: npm
✔ Found compatible package version: @angular/material@15.2.7.
✔ Package information loaded.

The package @angular/material@15.2.7 will be installed and executed.
Would you like to proceed? (Y/n)
```

Comment: why you want to skip prompts?

Comment: I wrote a script that installs material along with many other things, and being able to skip the prompts lets the script run without any outside help ...

Comment: Have you tried running this as a single line in a shell? Does the `--defaults` option work for you?

Comment: As far as I can tell it still works. What's made you think otherwise?

Comment: Jon I provided a sample command line attempt in the question for interactive=false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid the "Would you like to proceed?" prompt you need to add the option `--skip-confirmation`.

Description from the [docs](https://angular.io/cli/add#options):

> Skip asking a confirmation prompt before installing and executing the package. Ensure package name is correct prior to using this option.

Comment: Just a note ... I had to add `--defaults` also to get it to run completely prompt free.